# Input vector without temporary variable

Tags: c++, vector, input

How do I input vector without a temporary variable(like x in this example)?

```
std::vector<int> a;
int n, x;
std::cin >> n;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    std::cin >> x;
    a.push_back(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
int n, x;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<int> a(n);
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    std::cin >> a[i];
}
```